# Identifying a SOIC-8 IC with “302F” marking

Tags: batteries, identification, circuit-protection

I have a board with an unidentified SOIC-8 IC marked "302F".

[image: ERA-201B1]

I am looking for the part number of this component which is mounted as IC21 in the PCB, itself part of the ERA-201B1 2 cell battery pack designed for Aibo ERS-210 and ERS-220 robots by Sony in 1999-2000.

This battery PCB includes also a TI bq2040 fuel gauge and a Seiko Instruments S-8232AAFT battery protection IC.

I would first like to know who you think would be the manufacturer of this component.

[image: Close-up photo of IC top markings]

Thanks for all the replies.

**Edit 1**: I add a part of the reverse engineering schematic I did. The naming and type of the pins is a guess for now.

[image: 302F reverse engineering schematic draft version]

What I'm sure is the connection between IC21, the power resources (BAT+ for 2 cell voltage, BATM for 1 cell voltage, BAT-) and other passive components.

**Edit 2**: Starting from the hypothesis of a Microchip part number and after completing the study of the ERA-201B1 PCB on which it is mounted, I compared its potential function with that of similar components.

[image: 302F reverse engineering schematic release 1.2]

**Edit 3**: For those interested, I posted the reverse engineering schematic of the Sony Aibo ERA-201B1 PCB that I made on Github:
https://github.com/lpollier/battmon/blob/master/example/ERA-201B1_reverse_engineering_schematic.pdf

Comment: Logo is Microchip Technology

Comment: I'm not sure it's a Microchip logo.  Theirs is slightly different: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/about/legal-information/microchip-trademarks/_jcr_content/root/responsivegrid/container_758173909/image_1193914355.coreimg.png/1594177816975/microchip-round-logo.png

Comment: I also thought it was a Microchip quite intuitively at first.

The logo is the same but it is marked in negative without the circle in which it is traditionally inscribed on all types of cases since before the 2000s.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to what this 302f is or indeed have any findings on aibo batteries to share?

Comment: Yes @looxuser, I offered an explanation on the identification and the operation of this IC marked 302F in the **Edit 2** part of my request and I released a first version of the ERA-201B1 reverse engineering schematic that you can find in **Edit 3**.

Comment: hi thanks for the links to edits 2 and 3. Can i test my narrative of operation to you please? I'm using an earlier ERS111 for reference:- So the dale current sensing resistor provides a value to IC21 and that then in turn decides whether the heat the fusable element through a mosfet? that fusaible element is in series anyway to the supply voltage from the battery to the aibo? Cheers Andy

Comment: @Andyg I think the 2 current sensing resistors R55/R56 marked "DALE" are only used by the bq2040 gas gauge IC41, for both measuring the real time current and estimate the remaining capacity before the next full charge. You can see on the bq2040 datasheet that the reference design is very close to the one integrated in the ERA-201B schematic.

Comment: @Andyg Independently of these components, it is true that the fuse F1 is in series of the 2 Li-Ion cells, and probably should be burnt out when transistor Q8 is active, which seems to be the case when the output of IC21 is at high level after an overvoltage detection in BAT+ or BATM. This function with the fuse is sometimes called "secondary level battery protection".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Furrtek](https://github.com/furrtek) who opened an issue on [Github](https://github.com/lpollier/battmon/issues/4), it turns out that the part number of IC21 is [MM1302F](https://cdn.datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/M/M/1/MM1302F_MITSUMIELECTRIC.pdf), and it is a 2-cell Li-ion battery over-voltage protection.

[image: 302F reverse engineering schematic release 1.3]

*Figure 1. 302F reverse engineering schematic release 1.3*

Although the [link](https://rtellason.com/semiconductorlogos.html) provided in a [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/550228/identifying-a-soic-8-ic-with-302f-marking#comment1511332_550230) by [Theodore](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/66767/theodore) tells us that the logo is that of Microchip, this [one](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Mitsumi) actually corresponds to the Japanese company [Mitsumi](https://www.mitsumi.co.jp).

[image: Microchip vs Mitsumi logos]

*Figure 2. Microchip vs Mitsumi logos*

[image: Mitsumi logo 1990s]

*Figure 3. Mitsumi logo 1990s*

---

Finally I was able to complete my research and offer the owners of Aibo robots of the ERS-210, ERS-210A and ERS-220 series tools to read your battery and refill it yourself.

For the most curious and skilled in electronics, you can find a full tutorial on how to replace the cells, update EEPROM settings accordingly to their capacity, and reinitialize the first level battery protection:
https://github.com/lpollier/battmon/blob/master/example/ERA-201B1_recell_tutorial.pdf

In addition, I also offer a ERA-201B1 battery parameters reader named BattMon 2.0 made with an Arduino Uno and a 2x16 LCD keypad shield:
https://github.com/lpollier/battmon

[image: ERA-201B1 wiring diagram]

*Figure 4. ERA-201B1 wiring diagram*

Answer (score 1):

The logo on that chip resembles that of [Microchip Technology Incorporated](https://www.microchip.com/).

They are the makers of the famous PIC microcontrollers and now own the AVR line as well. They, of course, make many other chips.

The logo is usually inverted from that and in a circle, so it may be something else. I couldn't find a closer match.

A website like [THIS](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/?method=logo) can be useful to find IC logos.

Thanks to @Theodore: [HERE](http://rtellason.com/semiconductorlogos.html) is a link that shows the exact logo. It is indeed Microchip.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I'm not sure it is Microchip. Since the logo mark is looking identical but written in negative, and without the circle that usually surrounds the logo on any packages.

Comment: Pretty sure you are correct.  I've been screwing around with ICs for 20+ years and don't recognize it, it may be some no-name manufacturer that is hoping to be mistaken for Microchip.  None of my IC logo resources have that exact logo.  Sorry, and good luck!

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help and experience #evildemonic.

Comment: Here is another logo listing: [Semiconductor Manufacturer Logos](http://rtellason.com/semiconductorlogos.html)

Comment: Your link confirms that the logo is also Microchip. Thanks a lot @Theodore.